# Globalization / multilanguage in WPF vb.net using Ressourcedictionaries .xaml

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, globalization

What is the best practice to set up a Multilingual App?

I already have a working project with Ressource-dictionaries. But it looks different to this Topic:
[MSDN globalization-and-localization-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

This is my approach

Application.Xaml:

```
    <Application.Resources >
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Ressources/Lang_EN.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

Project-Explorer:

[Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks95s.png)

Inside a File Lang_EN.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<!--Public Enum SpindleType
    Milling_Spindle = 0
    Main_Spindle = 1
    Sub_Spindle = 2
    Grinding_Spindle = 3
End Enum-->

<system:String x:Key="Timer">Timer</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="Drehzahl">Speed</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="APIStatus">API Status</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="MachineType">Machine type</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="MachineSN">Machine S/N</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="SpindleSN">Spindle S/N</system:String>
```

In my MainWindow.xaml.vb i have following sub that changes the UI Language:

```
 Private Sub Button_NL_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button_NL.Click
    NewDictSource("\Ressources\Lang_NL.xaml")
 End Sub
```

The Mainwindow.xaml looks like that:

```
<TextBlock
                        x:Name="lbl_Timer_block3"
                        MinWidth="120"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="{DynamicResource Timer}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
```

Here in the MainWindow.xaml i use the Dynamic Ressource dictionary i declared in Application.xaml before.

Do you have a nicer and more easy way to do this?

Comment: I'm used to doing this through separate .resx files for different locales, e.g. Resources.resx as the main, then Resources.zh-hans.resx for Chinese, and so-on.  Then, there isn't any special handling in the XAML, the text is referenced using static references to the resources (e.g. `Text={x:Static res:Resources.MyText}`) and the locale-based text lookup does its thing.

Comment: Thanks @Craig ! That sounds good. i heard of .resx before. In your case, how do you handle the Change of the Language at Runtime ? e.g. per Button Click Event

Comment: The software I work on has an option to select the preferred language, and we manipulate the UI culture settings based on that.  Those variables will pick up default settings based on the user's Windows display language and regional settings.  Some of the things to look at are `Thread.CurrentCulture`, `Thread.CurrentUICulture`, `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`, and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`.  I think you should generally prefer the "UI" versions as these will set the culture used for resource lookups.

Comment: Note that this may also start to influence things like decimal separators, which can affect parsing of decimal / floating point numbers.

Comment: Yes, I am using the UI Culture Setting already (I did not post it but in the code I use it while initializing the window). Do you have a reference guide on how to use these .resx files? I really struggle with these and need a very beginner friendly guide if possible.

Comment: Which part of using resx files gives you trouble?  There isn't anything special to doing the language files; they just redefine resources with the same name as in the "master" file.  The master resource will be used if there isn't a language-specific resource.

Comment: Also of note---there isn't necessarily anything wrong with what you're doing right now as long as it works for you.

Comment: Hey @Craig, i have no example for .resx files and don't know how to implement them. But thanks for telling me my way is okay. It is fast and easy implementet in future projects so maybe i just dump the idea of .resx files. But somehow i am a bit curious about that topic :)

Comment: My apologies, I forgot that Visual Studio's support for resx files in VB projects is a little spotty.  My default, you have access to resources through My Project, which will edit My Project\Resources.resx (and the associated generated code file My Project\Resources.vb).  You can then add language versions of the resource files directly to the project as EmbeddedResource (my reference project has them in the same ItemGroup as the main resource file) without the Generator/LastGenOutput/CustomToolNamespace nodes.

Comment: For the "My" resources, you don't get access to the language resx files through the solution explorer; you would have to open them manually to edit them in the IDE.

Comment: You can also add top-level resources into the project.  There appears to be support for this in the IDE.  I don't remember if there needs to be additional tweaking to the project file for this to work, and I haven't done language resources in a VB project through this route (in my case, the projects that have language resources like this are C# projects).